# How can I mock the Parent accessor of a faked TreeNode in a unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, kentico, nsubstitute

Using Kentico 12 SP, hotfix 64 - I can create faked *TreeNode* types and set values on most of the fields, but I can't set a return value for **Parent** which I need to do to run a test on a method.

The method I'm trying to test:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GenerateBreadcrumbs(TreeNode treeNode)
{
    var breadcrumbs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    if (treeNode != null) {
        var revBreadcrumbs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var thisNode = (treeNode.Parent != null && treeNode.Parent.NodeAliasPath != "/") ? treeNode.Parent : null;
        while (thisNode != null) {
            revBreadcrumbs.Add(thisNode.DocumentName, thisNode.NodeAliasPath.ToLowerInvariant());
            thisNode = (thisNode.Parent != null && thisNode.Parent.NodeAliasPath != "/") ? thisNode.Parent : null;
        }
        foreach (var item in revBreadcrumbs.Reverse())
        {
            breadcrumbs.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }
    return breadcrumbs;
}
```

In the unit test I can *Fake* a document type of type *Folder*

```
DocumentGenerator.RegisterDocumentType<Folder>(Folder.CLASS_NAME);
Fake().DocumentType<Folder>(Folder.CLASS_NAME);
```

I can create instances and set values on other properties and they work as expected

```
Folder baseFolder = TreeNode.New<Folder>()
    .With(f => f.SetValue("DocumentName", docName))
    .With(f => f.SetValue("NodeAliasPath", docPath));
```

But when I try to set the return value for "Parent" it ignores that value when called by the method being tested.

```
Folder underFolder= TreeNode.New<Folder>()
    .With(f => f.SetValue("Parent", baseFolder));
```

I've tried using NSubstitute to change the return value of *Parent* `underFolder.Parent.Returns(baseFolder);` but it throws an exception `"NSubstitute.Exceptions.CouldNotSetReturnDueToNoLastCallException : Could not find a call to return from."`.

Searches on this error seem to indicate that I did not fake the class in the manner NSubstitute expected, which would be something like this: `var mockFolder = Substitute.For<Folder>();`  I tried the Moq version too, both returned the error `System.TypeLoadException : Method 'DeleteInternal' on type 'Castle.Proxies.FolderProxy' from assembly 'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2...` indicating that one or more properties of TreeNode can't be read by the mocking frameworks... ugh.

Anyway, should I be using a different strategy for testing this? I didn't want to have to write a wrapper for TreeNode but seems like I may have to to get this tested?

Comment: Is it possible to use a `TreeNode` instances for tests? Due to the level of interaction with these classes I think it would make for a more reliable test.

Comment: Thank you, @DavidTchepak - Yes it is, but changing the type to `TreeNode` doesn't change the behavior since `Folder` implements `TreeNode`.  The signature for parent is `public virtual TreeNode Parent { get; }`, should I be using a different method to mock this property?

Comment: I meant to use the real classes rather than mocks. The API looks quite large which can make mocking problematic. In terms of the error you're seeing, try adding [NSubstitute.Analyzers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/nsubstitute-analysers/) to the test project and see if it detects problems like [internal member use](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute.Analyzers/blob/master/documentation/rules/NS1003.md).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is going to be possible with a Unit Test.

`TreeNode.Parent` is not a field/primitive value that is backed by a database field (even though `NodeParentID` is), so using `.SetValue()` is not going to have any effect.

In the source code, the `TreeNode.Parent` property makes at least 1 database query (potentially 2), and neither of these is handled by the Kentico Unit Test infrastructure.

My recommendation would be to use 1 of 2 options.

1. Isolate your use of `TreeNode.Parent` by using an abstraction to get its value from a `TreeNode`, and then create a stub in your test using something like `NSubstitute` (or manually).

```cs
public interface ITreeNodeAccessor
{
    TreeNode GetParent(TreeNode node);
}
```

2. Switch to an [Integration Test](https://docs.xperience.io/k12sp/custom-development/writing-automated-tests/creating-integration-tests-with-a-connection-string).

I've personally taken both approaches when the Unit Test infrastructure fails to handle my use case - the one I take depends on what it is I'm actually trying to test.

Comment: This is the solution I used to get the test working, thank you. In this case I'm only testing the logic so a unit test was more appropriate in my opinion. I was thinking about writing a wrapper for this specific scenario but adding an interface `IParentAccessor` with `TreeNode GetParent(TreeNode node);` and having the partial `Folder` class implement it ended up being a good solution with very little refactoring.